# How do I implement summation and array iteration correctly based on Pseudo code. PYTHON Relaxation Method

Tags: python, iteration, numerical-methods

I am trying to implement relaxation iterative solver for a project. The function we create should intake two inputs: Matrix A, and Vector B, and should return iterative vectors X that Approximate solution Ax = b.

Pseudo Code from the book is here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nEQA.png)

I am new to Python so I am struggling quite a bit with implementing this method. Here is my code:

```
def SOR_1(A,b):
k=1
n = len(A)
xo = np.zeros_like(b)
x = np.zeros_like(b)
omega = 1.25
while (k <= N):
    for i in range(n-1):
        x[i] = (1.0-omega)*xo[i] + (1.0/A[i][i])[omega(-np.sum(A[i][j]*x[j]))
        -np.sum(A[i][j]*xo[j] + b[i])]
        if ( np.linalg.norm(x - xo) < 1e-9):
                print (x)

        k = k + 1.0
            for i in range(n-1):
                xo[i] = x[i]

return x
```

My question is how do I implement the for loop and generating the arrays correctly based off of the Pseudo Code.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Python!

Variables in Python are case sensitive so `n` is defined but `N` is not defined. If they are supposed to be different variables, I don't see what your value is for `N`.

You are off to a good start but the following line is still psuedocode for the most part:

```
x[i] = (1.0-omega)*xo[i] + (1.0/A[i][i])[omega(-np.sum(A[i][j]*x[j]))
    -np.sum(A[i][j]*xo[j] + b[i])]
```

In the textbook's pseudocode square brackets are being used as a grouping symbol but in Python, they are reserved for creating and accessing lists (which is what python calls arrays). Also, there is no implicit multiplication in Python so you have to write things like `(1 + 2)*(3*(4+5))` rather than `(1 + 2)[3(4+5)]`

The other major issue is that you don't define j. You probably need a for loop that would either look like:

```
for j in range(1, i):
```

or if you want to do it inline

```
sum(A[i][j]*x[j] for j in range(1, i))
```

Note that range has two arguments, where to start and what value to stop before so range(1, i) is equivalent to the summation from 1 to i - 1

I think you are struggling with that line because there's far too much going on in that line. See if you can figure out parts of it using separate variables or offload some of the work to separate functions.

something like: `x[i] =a + b * c * d() - e()` but give a,b c, d and e meaningful names. You'd then have to correctly set each variable and define each function but at least you are trying to solve separate problems rather than one huge complex one.

Also, make sure you have your tabs correct. `k = k + 1.0` should not be inside that for loop, just inside the while loop.

Coding is an iterative process. First get the while loop working. Don't try to do anything in it (except print out the variable so you can see that it is working). Next get the for loop working inside the while loop (again, just printing the variables). Next get (1.0-omega)*xo[i] working. Along the way, you'll discover and solve issues such as (1.0-omega)*xo[i] will evaluate to 0 because xo is a NumPy list initiated with all zeros.

You'd start with something like:

```
k = 1
N = 3
n = 3
xo = [1, 2, 3]
while (k <= N):
    for i in range(n):
      print(k, i)
      omega = 1.25
      print((1.0-omega)*xo[i])
    k += 1
```

And slowly work more and more of the relaxation solver in until you have everything working.